# I need to open a password protected VBA project in an Excel file

Tags: vba, passwords, protected

I have an excel file with a VBA Project which is password protected. How can I unlock the file? The person who created this is no longer working and I have to unlock this file to make work easier.

Thanks in advance
Syed

Comment: Which version of Excel?  Is it an .xls or an .xlsx file?  And to clarify, you need to get into the VBA, not the file in general, right?

Answer (score 1):

**This only works on four letter extension Excel files:**

1. Download HexEdit from this address: http://www.physics.ohio-state.edu/~prewett/hexedit/
2. Change the extension of the Excel file to ".zip"
3. Open the file in WinZip
4. Find and change the name of the file "vbaProject.bin" to "vbaProject.bin1"
5. Extract the "vbaProject.bin1" file and open it in HexEdit
6. Search for the phrase "DPB" in the file and change it to "DPx"
7. Save the fileand remove the "1" at the end of the extension
8. Import the file back in the .zip file right next to "vbaProject.bin1" file
9. Delete the "vbaProject.bin1" file, save the .zip file and change the extension back to Excel
10. Open the Excel file. It will error, but click "OK" or similar

Comment: Then you need to add a new password to actually view the code, otherwise you get `Unexpected error (40230)`